# How to sort a large number of lists to get a top 10 of the longest lists

Tags: python, list

So I have a text file with around 400,000 lists that mostly look like this.

```
100005  127545  202036  257630  362970  376927  429080
10001   27638   51569   88226   116422  126227  159947  162938  184977  188045
191044  246142  265214  290507  296858  300258  341525  348922  359832  365744
382502  390538  410857  433453  479170  489980  540746
10001   27638   51569   88226   116422  126227  159947  162938  184977  188045
191044  246142  265214  290507  300258  341525  348922  359832  365744  382502
```

So far I have a for loop that goes line by line and turns the current line into a temp array list.

How would I create a top ten list that has the list with the most elements of the whole file.

This is the code I have now.

```
file = open('node.txt', 'r')

adj = {}
top_ten = []
at_least_3 = 0

for line in file:
    data = line.split()
    adj[data[0]] = data[1:]
```

And this is what one of the list look like

```
['99995', '110038', '330533', '333808', '344852', '376948', '470766', '499315']
```

Comment: Can you provide a part of the created Python list?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Keep a dict with keys as the numbers and values as the count.

Comment: If people could unravel their downvotes, it might encourage the OP

Answer (score 2):

```
# collect the lines
lines = []

with open("so.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # split each line into a list
        lines.append(line.split())

# sort the lines by length, descending
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: -len(x))

# print the first 10 lines
print(lines[:10])
```

Comment: There is no need to use `readlines`. Just `for line in f:` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) to display the top 10? i.e.:

```
import re
import collections

file = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
content = file.read()
numbers = re.findall(r"\d+", content)
counter = collections.Counter(numbers)
print(counter.most_common(10))
```

---

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/yRI7rK)

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question, which wants to know the 10 longest lists in the file.

Comment: Hum..I guess I didn't! In your option the OP wants to get the lines with highest number of records ?

Comment: That would be my guess.

Answer (score 1):

When wanting to count and then find the one(s) with the highest counts, [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) comes to mind:

```
from collections import Counter

lists = Counter()
with open('node.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        values = line.split()
        lists[tuple(values)] = len(values)

print('Length  Data')
print('======  ====')
for values, length in lists.most_common(10):
    print('{:2d}      {}'.format(length, list(values)))
```

Output (using sample file data):

```
Length  Data
======  ====
10      ['191044', '246142', '265214', '290507', '300258', '341525', '348922', '359832', '365744', '382502']
10      ['191044', '246142', '265214', '290507', '296858', '300258', '341525', '348922', '359832', '365744']
10      ['10001', '27638', '51569', '88226', '116422', '126227', '159947', '162938', '184977', '188045']
 7      ['382502', '390538', '410857', '433453', '479170', '489980', '540746']
 7      ['100005', '127545', '202036', '257630', '362970', '376927', '429080']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and max() maybe?  You say you've got a for loop that's placing the values into a temp array.  From that you could use "max()" to pick out the largest value and put that into a list.

As an open for loop, something like appending max() to a new list:

```
newlist = []

for x in data:
    largest = max(x)
    newlist.append(largest)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
newlist = [max(x) for x in data]
```

Then from there you have to do the same process on the new list(s) until you get to the desired top 10 scenario.

EDIT:  I've just realised that i've misread your question.  You want to get the lists with the most elements, not the highest values.  Ok.

len() is a good one for this.

```
for x in data:
    if len(templist) > x:
        newlist.append(templist)
```

That would give you the current highest and from there you could create a top 10 list of lengths or of the temp lists themselves, or both.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is really as shown with each number the same length, then I would make a dictionary with key = line, value = length, get the top value / key pairs in the dictionary and voila.  Sounds easy enough.